# One submit button, data will pass to two views in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have form in `razor/html` with some `model` properties. By clicking `submit` button I want to pass those `model data` to two different views.

Which approach I have to follow for this?

Comment: When you click submit button data is passed to server not the views. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? What is the use case? Share the sample code also

Comment: Data will go to the controller first then view... I have code just form and submit button.... After clicking a submit button data goes to controller then view.. But I want to pass data to two views by controller.

Comment: You can create one main view and two partial views. Render partial views in the main view by passing the model . Set model type same for all 3 views. Return main view from the controller with model.

Answer (score 0):

To render two views you can call main view inside your controller.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
  return View();
}
```

In Index View, Call your two partial views as below.

```
@RenderPartial("_View1");
@RenderPartial("_View2");
```